# Get method name that is executed on cookbook (Chef)

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

First of all, I'm new to programming, also new to chef cookbooks. But I'm playing around and got stuck trying to figure out how get the cookbook block that got changed.

For example:

```
  cookbook_file '/etc/wil.conf' do
        source 'wil.conf'
        owner 'root'
        group 'root'
        mode '0644'
        action :create
      end
       cookbook_file '/etc/wel.conf' do
        source 'wel.conf'
        owner 'root'
        group 'root'
        mode '0644'
        action :create
      end

  ruby_block 'sendpost' do
        block do
            `curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"appId":"APP","category":"APPLICATION","waterMark":null,"timestamp":"{EVENT.DATE}","status":"{Active}","resource":"#{changed}","alertTime":"{EVENT.AGE}","gateway":"#{ENV['HOSTNAME']}"}' http://server:port/context`
        end
        action :nothing
        subscribes :run, 'cookbook_file[/etc/wil.conf]', :immediately
        subscribes :run, 'cookbook_file[/etc/wel.conf]', :immediately
      end
```

I'm versioning some config files, and wrote a ruby_block to send a post request, my question is, I'm trying to know which one of the two resources got changed, either:
 
wil.conf or
 
wel.conf

so in my curl, I would send along with my request the resource *cookbook_file name* block that was changed  ("resource":"{ ??? file that was changed ??? }")

I'm getting some host variables with #{ENV['HOSTNAME']}. 
How to get the block name that got change in runtime?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported directly. Resources don't have output values, or input values other than the compile-time properties.